# Missing required request header when doing request with CORS anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, cors-anywhere

I'm getting an error "Missing required request header. Must specify one of origin,x-requested-with".

At first, I was thinking there was an issue with the variable from the .env.local file but if I console.log it when doing the request I can see it is correct.

Here's the code

```js
let YELP_API_KEY;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    YELP_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_YELP_API_KEY;
} else {
    YELP_API_KEY = process.env.YELP_API_KEY;
}

const Yelp = {
    // Returns restaurant search resuts

    async searchRestaurants(text) {
        console.log(YELP_API_KEY);
        try {
            let response = await axios.get(
                `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?limit=12&term=${text.what}&location=${text.where}&sort_by=${text.sortBy}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
                    },
                }
            );

            return response.data.businesses;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return "Error";
        }
    },
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Apparently the issue was caused by a `;` at the end of the variable declaration in the `.env` file.

I was assuming you had to put a semicolon at the end of each string of code like in JS.

A silly mistake, but it took me ages to realise it.